# RL circuit: How to determine the equivalent resistance of the circuit?

Tags: resistors, passive-networks, time, circuits

So I'm working on an RL circuit and the solution is stated to be that R1 and R3 are in series, but I didn't think that was the case because they don't have the same current through them. Given solution says to add R1 + R3 in series and then use that equivalent resistance and add to R2 as if it were in parallel.

TL;DR: How do I find the equivalent resistance of the circuit below so that I can find the time constant for this RL circuit?

[image: Circuit]

Comment: In order to add `R1+R3` in series you'll have to transform `I1` into a voltage source. So `I1` becomes say `V1` with 600V and `R1` is now in series with `R3`. See [source transformation](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/source-transformation/)

Comment: Thevenin's Theorem says this voltage can be zero. For DC resonance I1 can be omitted because it does not change the RL resonance value as it is not a 'frequency'. Add `R1+R3` in series then add `R2` in parallel. Now you have your RL values.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to find the R-L time constant (L/R numerically) then the constant current generator has infinite impedance and can be ignored. This leaves R1 and R3 in series (R1+R3) in parallel with R2 hence the effective resistance of the circuit is: -

R2 || (R1 + R3)

Or do it using Thevenin's theorum; a current source in parallel with a resistor (R1) is equivalent to a voltage source in series with that resistor and this of course makes R1 in series with R3.